# How to create a table structure from column values of another table in Mysql and insert data

Tags: mysql, database

I want to create a table structure from column values of another table in Mysql and insert data.

I have queried below data set [Image 1] from two Db tables. I need to get a table like [Image 2] from below data set [Image 1]

Any suggestions please?

Image 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEIzA.png)

Image 2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1cZ5.png)

Comment: I recommend using a stored procedure that pulls all distinct attributes from table1 and creates a dynamic query to create a table2. Then, loop through table1's data and extract values and dump them in table2. Can you share a larger portion of table1 in text format (instead of image)?

Answer (score 0):

You Can try below query, Here you vahe to check attribute value statically & those will be fixed :

```
SELECT u_id , 
    MAX( CASE WHEN attribute = 'givenName' THEN 'GN' END ) as givenName, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'familyName' THEN 'FN' END) as familyName, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'emails' THEN 'E' END) as emails 
FROM column_row GROUP BY u_id
```